Show that $D = \ker(dx_3 - x_1 dx_2) \cap \ker (dx_1 - x_4 dx_2) \subset T \mathbb R^4$ is a distribution of rank two.
This question is from an old old public ally available  qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). All work is my own.

Show that $$D = \ker(dx_3 - x_1 dx_2) \cap \ker (dx_1 - x_4 dx_2) \subset T \mathbb R^4$$ is a distribution of rank two.

Answer: This is a pretty straightforward computation. Greek letters denote some real-valued constants. Take the vector space to have bases $\left\{ex_i \right\}_i $ dual to our $ \left \{dx_i \right \}_i$.
Regarding the first space being intersected:
$$ \ker_1 := \ker (dx_3 - x_1 dx_2 ) = \alpha  \, ex_1 + \beta (x_1 \, ex_3 + ex_2) + \gamma \, ex_4$$
for the second space being intersected:
$$ \ker_2  := \ker (dx_1 - x_4 \,dx_2) = \delta ( x_4 \, ex_1 + ex_2) + \varepsilon \, ex_3 + \zeta \, ex_4$$
it can be seen intuitively that $\dim \ker_1 = \dim \ker _2 = 3$. Now let's compute the dimension of both spaces added together:
\begin{align} \ker _1 + \ker _2 &= \alpha  \, ex_1 + \beta (x_1 \, ex_3 + ex_2) + \gamma \, ex_4 + \delta ( x_4 \, ex_1 + ex_2) + \varepsilon \, ex_3 + \zeta \, ex_4 \\ &=  \alpha  \, ex_1 + \beta \, x_1 \, ex_3 + \beta \, ex_2 + \gamma \, ex_4 + \delta \,  x_4 \, ex_1 + \delta \, ex_2 + \varepsilon \, ex_3 + \zeta \, ex_4 \\ &= \boxed{(\alpha + \delta \, x_4 ) ex_1 + (\beta + \delta )ex_2 + (\beta \, x_1 + \varepsilon)ex_3 + (\gamma + \zeta)ex_4} \end{align}
These terms can vary independently, so $\dim (ker_1 + ker_2) = 4$. Thus $$\dim (ker_1 \cap \ker_2) = \dim \ker_1 + \dim \ker_2 - \dim(\ker_1 + \ker _2) = 3 + 3 - 4 = 2$$ Smoothness is trivial to see.

(a) Is this correct. More importantly I feel that it's smooth because I can easily compute the derivatives and I see no undifferentiable behavior, but is it that easy to verify?

Why mess with all this horrid notation and dual bases? Are the two $1$-forms everywhere linearly independent? How can you check that in a second?

@TedShifrin I’ve never taken a dedicated linear algebra class, and it’s been five years since I took the required LA/ODE hybrid class that was required at UT Austin for my engineering degree. If there’s a faster check, give it as an answer and I’ll accept it.

I don't know if it's beneath your knowledge level or not, but allow me to recommend my YouTube lectures from a (quite) theoretical integrated course on linear algebra or multivariable calculus/analysis. They're linked in my profile, and some may be helpful.

Let $\omega=dx_3-x_1\,dx_2$ and $\phi=dx_1-x_4\,dx_2$. Then $\omega\wedge\phi=dx_3\wedge dx_1 + dx_2\wedge(x_4\,dx_3-x_1\wedge dx_1)$ is nowhere zero. (Note that $dx_3\wedge dx_1$, $dx_2\wedge dx_4$, and $dx_2\wedge dx_1$ are everywhere linearly independent.)
Since $\omega\wedge\phi\ne 0$, $\omega$ and $\phi$ are linearly independent at each point. Hence (at each point) the $3$-planes $\ker\omega$ and $\ker\phi$ are distinct and have a $2$-dimensional intersection.
In linear algebra terms, we can consider each of the $1$-forms as giving (pointwise) a linear map $\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R$, and so the pair give us a linear map $\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^2$, which is given by the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&-x_1&1&0 \\ 1&-x_4&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Since this matrix evidently has rank $2$, the kernel has dimension $4-2=2$ (at each point).
